# For-loop output explanation needed?

Tags: java, for-loop

I need an explanation of how the output prints 9(S), 7(S), 5(S) and 3(S).

10 > 3 is correct and goes to y 1 <= 2 which is correct so 2 x 10 - 2 = 18 but the output prints 9. I don't understand the logic here. Why does it print 9(s) instead of 18(s)?

```
public class Q2{
public static void main(String args[]) {
int x,y;
for(x= 10;  x > 3;  x = x - 2) {
        for(y = 1;  y <= 2 * x - 2;  y = y + 2)
            System.out.print("S");
            System.out.print("\n");
            } 
}  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its correct Y <= 18 , but you are incrementing Y by 2, so it gets printed 9 times.

Answer (score 0):

To understand, write down on a piece of paper what the values of your variables will be.

First, write down the values of `x`:

```
x:  10   8   6   4
```

Next, write down the calculated upper boundary value for `y`, i.e. the result of expression `2 * x - 2`:

```
x   :  10   8   6   4
yMax:  18  14  10   6
```

Last, write down the values of `y`:

```
x   :  10   8   6   4
yMax:  18  14  10   6
y   :   1   1   1   1
        3   3   3   3
        5   5   5   5
        7   7   7
        9   9   9
       11  11
       13  13
       15
       17
```

Finally, count the number of `y` values for each `x` value, i.e. the number of times `S` is printed:

```
x    :  10   8   6   4
count:   9   7   5   3
```

Then realize that the code would have been much easier to understand if it had just been written like this:

```
for (int count = 9; count >= 3; count -= 2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        System.out.println("S");
    }
}
```

Of course, that wouldn't have taught you what they were trying to teach you, which is:

*Conclusion:* If you don't understand what the code is doing, follow the logic step by step, and write down what it is doing.

Comment: Thank you for your time writing to me these steps for me to understand.